# how do I merge paper.js items into a raster image?

Tags: javascript, raster, paperjs

I am using paper.js to create an application in which I can markup an image then save it.

My lowest layer of my paper project is a raster of the image. The next layer up is where vector graphic markup is done using various paper.js items. When an item is committed I copy it to the lower (raster) layer where it is preserved. But it is just a child item of the layer, not part of the rasterized image. If I capture the raster as an image with toDataURL the child items are not part of the image (I wouldn't expect them to be).

How do I insert/overlay part of the rasterized image with an paper.js item? I can rasterize the item first, but then I need to know how to merge the two rasters with one overlaying part of the other? If I convert to a raster first then pixels that are not in the actual paperjs item but are in the enclosing rectangle will need to be transparent, i.e., not overlay the rasterized image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a raster object from the whole layer, then convert that to a DataURL string:

```
var tempImg = project.layers[0].rasterize();
var dataString = tempImg.toDataURL();
tempImg.remove();
```

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't obvious to me that I could just rasterize a layer. This does the trick perfectly.